# Docker image registries

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

We are using AWS **EC2 container services** and we are using Amazon container registry but the problem with container registry is that it's only available in one region although it's have URI but is **docker hub repository** is good to go with EC2 container services or using Amazon ECR.
Thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Question is docker hub is will good solution or Amazon ecr so can use one repo in testing and production in different region and different environment with tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on several factors.

If your images can be public or must be private. If you can make a public image, docker hub could work.

With ECR you will have a fine grain control of your permissions, integrated with IAM

On the other hand, ECR it's only available on one region so if you pull an image from a different region you will be charged for that traffic and the latency could be a problem so if you need a multi-region registry yo should implement that mechanism by yourself.

In brief, I wouldn't use public registry for production applications. You'll have more control with a private registry like ECR or other 3rd party solutions.